# How to update the canvas after a value?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to implement a clock using vanilla javascript.

The problem is the canvas doesn't update after it crosses 60 seconds. After every 60 seconds, it should start with an empty circle.

And when I apply the same logic that I use for mapping seconds to angle isn't working for minutes.

Here is what I have tried

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const mapTime = (value, x1, y1, x2, y2) => (value - x1) * (y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1) + x2;

setInterval(()=>{
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getSeconds(),0,360,0,60));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getMinutes(),0,360,0,60));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFAA00";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 60, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getHours(),0,360,0,24));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFAAFF";
  ctx.stroke();
},1000);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the canvas after each frame. Do something like this in the beginning of your draw function:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height)
```

Full code verified to work properly:

```
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

mapTime = (value, x1, y1, x2, y2) => (value - x1) * (y2 - x2) / (y1 - x1) + x2;

setInterval(()=>{
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width, c.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getSeconds(),0,360,0,60));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getMinutes(),0,360,0,60));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFAA00";
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 100, 60, 1.5*Math.PI, mapTime(new Date().getMinutes(),0,360,0,24));
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFAAFF";
  ctx.stroke();
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks @muusetail, I have already tried that. It doesn't work here.

Comment: I have tested your code with this line added and it works without problems, unless there is a problem outside of your provided segment

Answer (score 0):

Talking on a high level perspective, I think you can implement the following algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
val currentSeconds;
val currentMinutes;

updateEverySecond {
    increaseSecondOrSetTo0();
    drawClock(currentSeconds, currentMinutes);
}

updateEveryMinute {
    increaseMinuteOrSetTo0();
}
```